# getting rid of the batch effects

Tags: normalization, group-differences

I have a two data set one with $n=15$ another with $n=25$. Each set of data has around 90 variables. The data collected was experimental so when I try to combine my two datasets I see clear differences in some variables due to this batch effect. I see these variables in a scatterplot matrix and some of them do not show separation based upon batches while others clearly show a separation. Is there a way to normalize them to combine these two sets. I tried taking z scores on each of the set separately and combine them based upon their score. When I try to see scatterplot matrix of the z-scores, the batch effects are not visible. Is it a valid way to normalize?

Comment: You can use the `ber()` function in the R package [ber](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ber/index.html) or the `combat()` function in the Bioconductor package [sva](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/sva.html).