# How to remove "batch effects" and transform counts data?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, experiment-design, count-data, batch-normalization

I have 6 experiments ranging from 40 - 60 samples (rows) and ~4500 attributes (columns).  Each experimental run was done by a different technician on a different day so the results vary between runs but w/in each experimental run there is pretty good consistency.  I have heard of "regressing out" batch effects w/ generalized linear models but **how can this (or any batch effect removal) be applied to raw counts data to transform each of the datasets?**

I noticed this question: [getting rid of the batch effects](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56281/getting-rid-of-the-batch-effects) but there was no answer only a comment directing towards R packages. I tried installing it but there's a bunch of dependencies that I can't use.  I can try to code one up myself in Python but I need help with the logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a Python wrapper for this function: http://web.mit.edu/~r/current/arch/i386_linux26/lib/R/library/limma/html/removeBatchEffect.html

Essentially you give the function log-transformed counts (I did pseudo-count = 1 and log2 transformed) and a factor vector mapping the samples to batches.  The output of that I made linear by 2^x = linear-scale.

Hope this helps someone in the future.